# Retrieve database records in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, psql

My model named `Person` contains 3 columns namely `name`,`age`,`gender`.

Now how to get all the rows if the `gender = "male"`. I try to
fetch the data as shown below.

```
p = Person.find_by_gender("male")
```

The above statement properly worked. But it returns only 1 record. Because, the statement is converted to like following query.

```
SELECT  "persons".* FROM "persons" WHERE "persons"."gender" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["gender", "male"]]
```

Due to limit is set to 1 it returns only 1 record. So, **how to unset the limit?** My requirement to get all the records in table if `gender`
matches `"male"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `where`

```
Person.where(gender: "male")
```

`find` method always returns only one record

Answer (score 1):

In rails find methods always return single record that's why it returning single record.

```
Person.find_by_gender("male")
```

Use Where which give you array of matching records(which is ActiveRecord::Relation)

```
Person.where(:gender => "male")
```